# ¿When is it necessary to include a GROUP BY statement in a SQL Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When writing a query and using an aggregate function like AVG, SUM, or even COUNT or any function, I ran into a message reminding me to add a GROUP BY clause at the end. I would like to ask why is this necessary.

When this happened, I inserted the GROUP BY clause with the column involved in the aggregated function.

Answer (score 1):

When using an average function without `GROUP BY` you tell the DBMS that you want one total result row.

E.g. count all clients:

```
select count(*) from clients;
```

Sample result:

| COUNT |
| --- |
| 1000 |

If you want one result row per ___, you must use `GROUP BY ___`.

E.g. count all clients per company and job:

```
select job, company, count(*)
from clients
group by job, company
order by job, company;
```

Sample result:

| COMPANY | JOB | COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BIGCOMPANY | Buyer | 400 |
| BIGCOMPANY | Seller | 300 |
| SMALLCOMPANY | Buyer | 200 |
| SMALLCOMPANY | Seller | 100 |

Without the `GROUP BY` clause

```
select job, company, count(*)
from clients
order by job, company;
```

you'll get a syntax error, because by applying `COUNT` without `GROUP BY` you tell the DBMS you want one result row with the total, but which company is to be displayed then and which job? The query is incomplete and hence invalid.